# How to check if current user has a pending order for specific product in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a plugin for a customer
How can I retrieve order status of order that a user ordered in product page?
I should condition to show something in page if order-status of that order of that customer for that product is equal to `wc-pending`
So I'm in product page and want to show element based on order status of purchased product by logged in user, how can I achieve this goal?

```
    $orders = wc_get_orders($user_id);
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    <?php if(//status of purchased of current user for this product is equall wc-pending){ ?>
        <a href="<?php echo home_url('redirect-to-room/' . $product->get_id()) ?>" class="button alt">
            <?php _e('Enter room', 'skyroom') ?>
        </a>
    <?php } ?>
```

currently get orders list of current user but can not figure out how to get status of order of this product page.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The solution that seems simpler and cleaner to me is to create a custom user meta that will contain a value (to be used as a check, so most likely "true" or "false") when the status of an order changes to `wc-pending`. Then you will need to get the customer id from the order and add the custom meta. You can use WooCommerce's `woocommerce_order_status_changed` function to do this. https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.373

Answer (score 2):

`wc_get_orders` receives an array as input parameter:

```
$args = array(
    'status'    => 'wc-pending',  
    'customer'  => get_current_user_id(),  
);

$pending_orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

if( ! empty( $pending_orders ) ) {
    .............
}
```

Comment: What part of this code checks if the product is the the one we're interested in? It only checks user and order status, but the product?